# iis 10 .net core 2.1 website configuration error

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-2.2

Good Day,

I am running into an error that I have never run into before. I have a brand new server (Windows 2016) and I have added IIS 10 to it. I have also installed .net Core 2.1 and 2.2 runtime and SDKs onto the server. When I set up a .net Core 2.1 website, it appears to set up fine, but when I try to click on any of the features in the features view, I get a really generic error message (it happens for any .net Core website I set up). The error is an alert that states: **There was an error while performing this operation. Details: [empty] Filename: \\?\D:\Apps\Test\web.config Error: [empty]**

[image]

I found one place where this question was asked before, but I have IIS Rewrite 2.1, .net Core 2.1 and 2.2 and I have this site set up on another server (test env) and it works perfectly fine there! I have also made sure that IUSR and IIS_User both have read/write capabilities to the folder and every file in it.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you,
Tim

Comment: One of the typical mistakes on a new server, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html#background

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this sort of error normally means there is either something it doesn't like in the web.config (XML element it doesn't recognize) or the web.config is missing.

Normally (for me anyway) this is because I've forgotten to install URL Rewrite as that's pretty much the only "extra" thing I use - but you've got that covered already.

It might be worth checking that the App Pool for the site is configured correctly and running (should be same as your other machine, check the basic settings and the advanced).

The only other thing I can think of, is that you've installed some of the features for IIS through the Windows Features, but not all of them. I sometimes have to go back through the lists and make sure all the right things are definitely checked.

Last step would be to create a real simple little mini site, with just a default page, use the IIS GUI to change some site level settings so it creates its own web.config, make sure it runs, then have a look at the differences between the files.

Hope any of that helps

Comment: Also try checking the Event Log and see if there's any extra detail in there about your error

Comment: Though your recall on URL Rewrite module does go on the right track, this issue is more specific to ASP.NET Core.